# algorithm to read a matrix diagonally (all diagonalls)

Tags: algorithm, matrix

i need an algorith that can read a matrix diagonally (all diagonals).

Example of input and output:

input:

```
matrix = [
["a", "b", "c", "d"],
["e", "f", "g", "h"],
["i", "j", "k", "l"],
["m", "n", "o", "p"]
 ]
```

and the output have to be like this:

```
["a", "eb", "ifc", "mjgd", "nkh", "ol","p"]
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to think about this problem is that each cell on a single diagonal must satisfy  `x+y=d`  where d is the index of the diagonal(from 0 to n+m-2 inclusive).

You can loop over d and for each d loop over x. Using the equation above we get: `y=d-x`. I suggest you grab a paper and pen and derive the constraints for x yourself.

Anyway here's the working code:

```py
matrix = [
["a", "b", "c", "d"],
["e", "f", "g", "h"],
["i", "j", "k", "l"],
["m", "n", "o", "p"]
 ]

n = len(matrix)
m = len(matrix[0])


res = []
for d in range(n+m-1):
    cur = ""
    for x in range(max(0, d-m+1),min(n, d+1)):
        print(x, d-x)
        cur = matrix[x][d-x] + cur
    print('---')
    res.append(cur)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `n` be the number of rows (or columns), 
then the number of diagonals is `2*n-1`

For the first character of each string, we go down the first column,
once we reach the bottom left corner we start going across the bottom row

When adding characters to the strings, for every `[row][column]` that we are on, the next one we need to go to will be at `[row-1][column+1]`

Here a sample java code that adds the the diagonals as a string to an array, then prints the array out to stdout

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n = 4;  // number of rows
        String array[] = new String[2*n-1];  // array to hold the diagonals
        int arrayIndex = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 2*n-1; i++) {
            if (i < n) {  // until we reach the bottom left corner
                int row = i;  // for each row
                int column = 0;  // start from the left side
                String tmp = "";
                while (row >= 0)
                    tmp += m[row--][column++];
                array[arrayIndex++] = tmp;
            }
            else {  // after we've reached the bottom left corner
                int row = n-1;  // start from the bottom row
                int column = i-n+1;  // for each column
                String tmp = "";
                while (column < n)
                    tmp += m[row--][column++];
                array[arrayIndex++] = tmp;
            }
        }

        // prints out the array
        for (String s : array)
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    static String m[][] = {
        {"a", "b", "c", "d"},
        {"e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"i", "j", "k", "l"},
        {"m", "n", "o", "p"}
    };
```

Here is what stdout looks like

```
a eb ifc mjgd nkh ol p
```

Hope this helps :)